# How to get value from input with data from database

Tags: php, html, input

I am having a table with `<input type="text" name="' . $r['0'] . '" value="' . $r['0'] . '"`

populated from data that i fetch from database like this:

```
echo '<form id="actions" name="nonValidMainForm" method="post"><table border="2" width="100%">';
    echo "<tr><td><b>Index</b></td><td><b>Email </b></td> <td><b>Date</b></td> <td><b>Name</b></td> <td><b>Surname</b></td> <td><b>Telephone Number</b></td> <td><b>Street Adress</b></td><br/>";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $my[] = $r['0'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$roww++.'</td>';
        echo '<td>
                <input size="50%" type="text" name="' . $r['0'] . '" value="'.$r['0'].'">
                <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe">
            </td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['1'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['2'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['3'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['4'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['5'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($my);
    echo "</pre>";
    if(isset($_POST['unsubscribe'])){
        foreach($my as $key=>$value){
            $email = $value;
        }
        echo "<script>console.log( 'Value is: " . $email . "' );</script>";

    }

    echo '<button style="position:fixed;bottom:5;left:5;">Change</button>';
    echo '</table></form>';
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
if(isset($_POST['unsubscribe'])){
            $email = $POST['email'];
            echo "<script>console.log( 'Value is: " . $email . "' );</script>";
        }
```

But the value is empty

So each time i press unsubscribe button the corresponding email to be deleted. How is this possible?

Comment: have you tried any code yet?

Comment: yes i have tried but it does not work

Comment: Do you have an actual form?  How is the value being posted to the server?

Comment: its not posted i just want to get the value

Comment: @BRG: "Get the value" from *where*?  The code sample you demonstrate is looking for the value in a form post.  So if you're not performing a form post then why would you expect the value to be there?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i have a form in which i have input fields. The input fields are populated with data from the database. I want to know how will i get the value of each input type.

Comment: @BRG: Then show the form too.  Currently there isn't one in the code shown, so that seems likely to be the problem.

Comment: i have different name and value for every input type and i dont know how to get the value

Comment: Something that everyone answering failed to grasp here, is that the OP wants to delete selected entries from their db. `DELETE FROM table WHERE col='x'`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Oh, I don't think we necessarily missed that part.  But the OP needs to have a valid form which actually posts an identifier to the server first.  Baby steps :)

Comment: @David I misinterpreted the question then David, sorry about that ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form has many elements with the same `name`.  How can the browser determine which element's value to send to the server when the form is posted?  Generally the last one takes precedence, but I suspect that behavior may be undefined and browser-specific.

If each individual table row needs to be a separately post-able form, then each row needs its own form:

```
echo '<td>
        <form method="POST" action="somePage.php">
          <input size="50%" type="text" name="email" value="'.$r['0'].'">
          <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe">
        </form>
      </td>';
```

That way when the browser posts the form to the server, it knows specifically which `email` and `unsubscribe` elements to use.  Since there's only one of each for that form.

Comment: well so now how can i get the value of each input when i press the button next to it?

Comment: @BRG: That's exactly what this answer describes.  By having separate forms there is only ever one value posted to the server for that input.  So you'd get the value from `$_POST['email']`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` tag.

```
echo '<form>';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$roww++.'</td>';
    echo '<td>
        <input size="50%" type="text" name="email" value="'.$r['0'].'">
        <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe">
    </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['1'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['3'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['4'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['5'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['unsubscribe'])){
        $email = $POST['email'];
        echo "<script>console.log( 'Value is: " . $email . "' );</script>";
    }
```

Based on your code above it looks like it's a syntax error. Try the update below

```
if(isset($_POST['unsubscribe'])){
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            echo "<script>console.log( 'Value is: " . $email . "' );  </script>";
        }
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: yeah i did but still i get the last value only. he changed the $_POST